# AdSense Won't Show in Particular Places

Tags: google-adsense

I have my AdSense TAGS in a WordPress Ad Widget called Click Missile Pro. For some reason the Ads disappear on Mobile version or the [site](http://www.glammonitor.com). There should be a text unit (in the middle of the post) and 250x250 banner at the bottom. Can anyone check? I am frustrated. The technical support on the AdSense forums is pretty lack luster.

Comment: I wish I knew enough to answer your question. I can imagine how frustrated you are. Good Luck!

Comment: Does it still happen if you load the Adsense code out of the widget?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you fixed this.

[image: Imgur]   [image: Imgur]

For anyone else, you have to set the ad size to a mobile available size. If the ad is set to leaderboard 728x90, then it won't display on mobile. Instead, create a mobile specific ad unit, or change the ad size to a mobile-available size, or Responsive, which will size it automatically depending on available space and device.